# como evitar que un codigo php (laravel), instalado en una pc como desktop app, sea alterado

Tags: php

disculpen si la pregunta es larga

Lo que quiero no es evitar que otra persona tenga mi código fuente y pueda reutilizarlo. de hecho pienso subirlo a github cuando este estable.

lo que quiero es que ningún usuario del sistema pueda ir a la carpeta htdocs y alterar el código fuente para por ejemplo eliminar el sistema de login.

Se trata de un sistema para llevar un control de asistencia de trabajadores a eventos privativos realizando validaciones que varían según se desea ejemple (edad, tipo nomina, sexo, etc). y los eventos son fuera de la red de la empresa.

la aplicación debe ejecutarse utilizando electron y una computadora tendrá la aplicación como app desktop y como servidor de base de datos para las demás pc clientes del sistema.

Quiero recalcar que el servidor sera una pc desktop mas que sirve de servido laravel 5.4 y postgres.

Investigando entendí que hhvm no me da soporte para laravel 5.4.

es posible con una maquina virtual tipo virtualbox?

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo usas? Tanto si es windows como linux y los usuarios no tienen usuarios administradores tus datos estarán seguros si configuras los permisos correctamente.

Comment: El sistema operativo sera windows en la pc servidor. buen dato esa es una de la opciones mantengo vigente aunque nunca no he hecho, es una gran opcion.

Comment: http://www.ioncube.com/.
no necesitas comprar el paquete completo, tienen una opcion de "Online PHP Encoder" que  cobran segun la cantidad de archivos y es bastante economica.